# Symfony 4: cannot access as ROLE_ADMIN

Tags: symfony

My Roles column value: `["ROLE_ADMIN"]`

My Entity/User:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json", nullable=true)
 */
private $roles = [];

public function getRoles() : ?array { 
    $roles = $this->roles; 
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
    return array_unique($roles); 
}
```

The `$currentUser->getRoles();` gives me this in `var_dump`:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "ROLE_ADMIN" [1]=> string(9) "ROLE_USER" }
```

My security.yaml:

```
access_control:
- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The Profiler Toolbar tells me that I'm logged in.

But still I see the message:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\
AccessDeniedHttpException
```

But when I change my security.yaml to:

```
access_control:
- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Then the Exception disappears.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Even if I add the 'ROLE_ADMIN' to my getRoles(), it does not help

Comment: Have you logged out and logged in again and cleared the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Try to logout and login, symfony keeps roles in remember me token, you can check your currently assigned roles in profiler, security tab. Most probably role is not in remember me cookie, that's why it doesnt let you access.